# Unit Roots in Short Horizon

Tags: time-series, stationarity, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have a series that is stationary in the long run. However, in the model development sample - which is a short horizon - the same series is trending. Now, should I consider this series as non-stationary because it is trending in the model development sample? Looking for some reference articles.

Answer (score 2):

[Ornstein Uhlenbek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process) type of process produces non-stationary in short term and mean-reverting in long run series. A simple analog in discrete time is [AR(1) process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Example:_An_AR(1)_process):
$$x_t=\phi_1 x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t\\var(\varepsilon_t)=\sigma_\varepsilon^2$$
When the autoregressive coefficient $\phi_1=1-\lambda$ close to 1 i.e. $\lambda\to 0$, we have something that looks like a random walk in short range:
$$\Delta x_t\equiv x_t-x_{t-1}=-\lambda x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t\\
\Delta x_t\approx\varepsilon_t$$

In a long range it's still a stationary process with mean zero and variance:
$$var(x_t)=\frac{\sigma_\varepsilon^2}{\lambda}$$
If this was unit root ($\lambda=0$) then the variance would not be bounded: $$var(x_t)=\sigma_\varepsilon^2 t$$

Comment: What about an answer to the question *should I consider this series as non-stationary because it is trending in the model development sample*?

Comment: I don’t think there’s an absolute answer here, that’s the point I was trying to make. It’s not the choice between unit root and trend only

Comment: Thanks!........